# ffmpeg : error while re encoding video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to re-encoding video with ffmpeg, and I am getting this error :

```
[aac @ 0x3752e40] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
```

The command and the full output::

```
/root$ /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i http://website.com/uploads/usr_videos/MVI_05571.mp4  -b:v 500k  -threads 4 -vf scale=-1:144  -b:a 128k http://website.com/uploads/usr_videos/144p_output.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.5.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built on Feb 18 2015 01:39:38 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
configuration: 
libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from     'http://website.com/uploads/usr_videos/MVI_05571.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
Duration: 00:01:48.26, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 7122 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6990 kb/s, 29 fps, 29 tbr, 14848 tbn, 29 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
[aac @ 0x3752e40] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
```

So Could anyone till me what this error mean and how can I fix it ?
I am using ffmpeg version 2.5 on centOS server.

Answer (score 23):

The quick fix is to add the option `-strict -2` just before the last argument (the name of the output).

There are several different AAC encoders that FFmpeg can use.  For the best quality, use the `libfdk_aac` encoder.  Unfortunately the license of libfdk_aac is incompatible with the GPL, which means that the GPL does not permit distribution of an executable derived from both libx264 (GPL) (used for H.264 video encoding) and libfdk_aac (used for AAC audio encoding).  Nevertheless this can be a great choice if you build FFmpeg yourself.  If your FFmpeg was built with libfdk_aac then you can use it with the option `-c:a libfdk_aac` before the output file name.

FFmpeg also has an experimental built-in AAC encoder, which has lower quality at a given bitrate but a compatible license.  Because it is experimental it is not used by default, but it can be used if you include the option `-strict experimental` or `-strict -2` just before the output file name, to enable experimental codecs.

For further details see the [FFmpeg AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC).

Comment: @mark40 I tried to add -strict experimental or -strict -2 before the output file name and I get this error : Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

Comment: @AshrafHefny That is an issue with your output.  Try writing to a file instead, by changing the last argument to a simple file name.  Post a new question if you still can't get it to work.

Comment: As mark4o mentioned, it is very important to place the `-strict -2` option in the right position, as this is not mentioned at all in the ffmpeg output error. Just to make sure it is clear, it should be: `ffmpeg -i infile -strict -2 outfile`

Comment: As of FFmpeg 3.0 (Feb 2016), the FFmpeg built-in native AAC encoder is no longer experimental, so `-strict -2` is no longer required to use it.

Comment: +1 to @mark40's comment about placement of the -strict -2 option - it was having no effect until I found this

Answer (score 2):

The native FFmpeg AAC encoder (`-codec:a aac`) is no longer experimental as of 2015-12-05. Use a recent build from the current git master branch and you won't have to use the `-strict` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `aac` to encode stream programatically, you can enable the experimental feature in your `AVCodecContext` like following.

```
AVCodecContext* enc_ctx;
// ...
enc_ctx->strict_std_compliance = FF_COMPLIANCE_EXPERIMENTAL;
```